# How to export specific SSRS tablix from textbox click

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report having multiple charts and tables.
I wanted to put a textbox on top and on click, it should export **particular** tablix/matrix on excel sheet.
It would be great if I get some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a combination of a

- hidden parameter the render format property.
- the RENDERFORMAT property
- Custom URL to action the export

The idea is to create a URL that will run your report with a parameter value that determines what objects to render.

Create a report, then add your tables/charts as required.

Next, create a parameter called `PrintOption` and set the default value to 0

If we wanted an option to only print tables for example, then we could say ...

"When PrintOption = 1 and exporting to excel then show the table".  As we have to set 'hidden' property we just need to reverse the logic and say

"When the PrintOption parameter is 1 AND we are exporting to excel then set the hidden property to False, else Set it to false". Actually this is still not quite right as we also want to show it when the format is RPL (interactive)

So, in the hidden property of the tables you want to export when the parameter is 1 set the expression to this

```
=IIF(
    Parameters!PrintOption.Value = 1 
        AND (Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPEMXML" OR Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL"),
    False,
    IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name =RPL", False, True)
    )
```

Repeat the process for other 'groups of objects' setting the PrintOption.Value to the value you want that object to be exported under.

Next, create a text for each group of objects (so for each PrintOption value you have used above, create a separate textbox. Label the text box as required e.g. "Export Tables Only"

In the textbox properties set the 'Action' to URL and the click the function ('fn')  button. Set the expression to

```
=Globals!ReportServerUrl & "?" 
&  Globals!ReportFolder & "/" 
& Globals!ReportName 
& "&PrintOption=1"
& "&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML"
```

Repeat for each textbox, changing the PrintOption number each time.

Finally, you can, optionally, set the parameter to be hidden but I normally test everything with it visible first.

When you click the button, it will open the generated url which will run the report with the selected parameter and save the file as Excel. As it is being rendered the hidden property is evaluated on only the configured objects will be rendered.

**Notes:**

- that you will have to deploy the report to test this.
- this was done from memory so is untested. There may be some minor mistakes but I know this process works as I have done it in the past.